# Show 3D camera orientation options in a more user friendly way

Tags: 3d

Currently we have the following camera options for the 3D preview of an object in our software.
[image]

I can imagine for some users that it's hard to visualize in their head which part of the object will be visible. How can I make this more user friendly for the users? Should I put icons next to the options?

Comment: How about having a sample object being shown from the camera's perspective in a preview window next or below the selector?

Answer (score 1):

The 3D environment is considered in 3 axes, which is not easy to visualize for a non-professional user

In more immersive environments and advanced interfaces (Cinema,Blender).
it is good to use options specific to reality.

[image]

---

However, if we do not have such a possibility, it is worth using the icons you mentioned

you can also use the clickable icon, but this pattern may not be intuitive enough

[image]

---

Edit:

I'm not sure it's correct- isometric left proposition

[image]

Dimensions to visualise:

[image]

Comment: I kind of like the clickable icon, I'm curious how something like 'isometric left' can be displayed